# Python re.search not working

Tags: python, regex

Facing nonetypr object error in below code
can anyone please help ?

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import re, os

featureList = {}
featureFileNames = {}

tempList = [f for f in listdir('.') if isfile(join('.', f))]

for fileName in tempList:
  fileName = '.' + os.sep + fileName
  featureFile = open(fileName, 'r')
  featureInfo = featureFile.readlines(-1)
  featureFile.close()
  featureName = re.search(r'.*XYZ : +(\S+\d)',' '.join(featureInfo)).group(1)
  featureList[featureName]=fileName  

I do have more than one files are in the below format :
file 1 : 
ABC : 123
ASD : 1234
SADF : 2412
XYZ : 123

file2:
ABC : 3234
ASD : 123323
SADF : 12345
XYZ : 1234555
```

I am unable to get where the error is ?
can someone please tell me what is the error and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Please provide `traceback`.

Comment: why are you removing the last line in text while reading `featureInfo = featureFile.readlines(-1)`

Comment: What are you trying to capture and your regex matches nothing so it is throwing None type error

Comment: The file contains `XYZ :`, you are searching for `XYZ:` (no space), so there is no match.

Comment: I am sorry, I have updated the code for "XYZ : ". I want to find "XYZ" string from all files given. I do not have any idea about what is reason for none type object. I am getting null values in search result. Could you please suggest me if better solution for this ? I  @The6thSense : I am removing last line because I have empty last line in every files. The string I am matching in my file is "strength-value".I used XYZ for this example

Answer (score 2):

In your code sample, the regex expression can not match the file examples you gave. There is a missing whitespace after `XYZ`:

```
  featureName = re.search(r'.*XYZ : +(\S+\d)',' '.join(featureInfo)).group(1)
```

Moreover to avoid NoneType errors, you should test the result of your `re.search` before using it as a map key.